# Wireless control of trailer board lights

Tags: obd-ii

Is there a (Bluetooth?) OBD module that can transmit to a receiver that remote controls a car trailer board lights ?
I have seen the magnetic bluetooth "stick on lights" that are powered by internal rechargeable battery and claim a 20 meter signal range from a bluetooth paired transmitter plugged in to the car's existing wired 7 pin car trailer socket.
What would be useful is if the above transmitter derived its signals whilst plugged into a car's OBD port.Such a device would eliminate splicing into the wiring loom as necessary for a conventional hook up.
In short are the side lights/ brake/indicator/and license plate illumination signals incorporated in the OBD ?

Comment: So what about the shielding of the car body and dash etc? The trailer socket is usually outside the vehicle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! For the most part no. These are operated by the Body Control Module (BCM) ... I believe almost exclusively. I would doubt the signalling from a switch to the BCM even goes through the CANBus network, but through its own wiring.

Comment: Solar Mike, good point, but even if the advertised 20 meter Bluetooth range was restricted to half due to shielding, 10 meters (30plus feet) should be adequate for reliable operation?    The reason for raising this topic is that I very rarely use a trailer and although fitted a tow bar am reluctant to splice into the existing wiring cautious of the can bus sensitivity.    I'm thinking that in staying with the motive for the Bluetooth temporary magnetic trailer lights why not  have the transmitter module on the end of a cable extended to the back seat /rear window closer to the receiver?

Comment: So how do the ones used by the heavy haulage breakdown companies work?

Comment: By the time you do all that with a bluetooth module you could have run a physical connector which would be more reliable. Bluetooth is fine for syncing watches to phones and headsets for boring work phone calls, I'm not sure I'd trust my life to it.

Comment: Solar Mike....Good question ...How do the heavy haulage breakdown companies enable their trailer lights?  I can only surmise they have a conventional wired socket to which they plug in an extendable cable that reaches to the required distance.

Comment: GdD...Thanks for the input but my question was :Is there a commercially available bluetooth transmitter that derives it's signals from a OBD socket? If so this would negate the need to wire a conventional 7 pin trailer board socket if the transmitter was paired to advertised magnetic Bluetooth trailer lights.I would not be happy to trust my life to a bluetooth device ,but see this as no more untrustworthy than the potential breakdown of any of the 14 mechanical electrical connectors involved in a conventional trailer board .This might prove a alternative to splicing the car's existing wiring.

Comment: On reflection of my question and responding answers.....,I need to steer away from the reliance of Bluetooth as the method of communicating from OBD to trailer board..........I did place a question mark after the first mention of Bluetooth as half of the exercise already uses this technology.... I appreciate that Bluetooth range is limited and so any acceptable RF carrier could be employed ,some of which do involve 'trust' and 'life' in everyday application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on a very good path with this. Between 2022 and 2024 Hyundai changed the wiring in the Palisade so that you  have to attach directly to each tail light and the battery to install even with the Curt adapter. For as infrequently as I haul a trailer I'd love an OBD2 wireless solution. My idea would be a cigarette lighter powered receiver that had the 4-way output for the trailer. I might just try to rig this up with an ESP32 and some relays. Cheers